# Kinect won't show on arch, but it show on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, manjaro

I have problem with connecting kinect to arch. When I type lsusb it show 3 devices, motor camera and i think audio, and I can even use it in processing.
But, when I type lsusb in terminal on arch it shows only motor. 
Dmesg command shows me when I connect my device:

```
new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 2252.040939] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2252.040963] hub 3-3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 2252.660652] usb 3-3.2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2254.158266] usb 3-3.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2254.984948] usb 3-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

Do you have maybe some advice or any idea what is happening? I have Manjaro distribution with xfce and default kernel was 4.1.16-1 version, and I event tried with 3.19.8.13.-1 kernel because ubuntu was using 3.19.0-44 kernel version and its working. It works on my older notebook too. So, it eliminates problem with 12V power supply :)
P.S. I have freenect drivers, openni and nite installed. I installed every driver from AUR and deleted if afterwards beacause it was not working.

edit: kinect is 1414 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was in /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend file, if device is not active it will turn it off, so I set number to -1, which will not suspend device which is not communicating at the moment.